# Convert EPS images to JPG using Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-imaging-library

I am working on a script that will generate a succession of images drawn using the python turtle module.  In researching this I have found that I will probably be only able to get EPS images out of turtle which I have been successful in doing.  For a quick demo of this I then had to use Photoshop to batch convert the images.  I would therefore obviously like to do the conversion within the script.

1. Draw a frame using turtle
2. Get the frame in EPS
3. Convert the frame to
   JPG
4. Repeat

Within the script are two functions I have tried as well as a simplified bit of conversion code within the for loop.  The first function produces an error message and the second function does nothing.  Within the simplified conversion code within the for loop I have identified the line which is causing the issue which probably has something to do with the save method.

I am using the latest version of Pillow with Python 3.4 and have removed PIL.  Based on a response below I have also tried adding ghostscript but this isn't supported in Python 3.

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3

from turtle import *
from PIL import Image #imports image class
import random
import os, sys

title("Vine Video")
setup(480, 480, 0, 0)
delay(0)
hideturtle()

colormode(255)

def saveImage(fileName):
    turtleImage = getscreen()
    turtleImage.getcanvas().postscript(file=fileName+".eps")
    print("File saved as ",fileName+".eps")

###Functions which haven't worked so far

##def eps2jpg(): ### Convert .eps files to .jpg - function from @trevorappleton
## 
##    openFiles = glob.glob('*.eps')
##    for files in openFiles:
## 
##        inFile = Image.open(files)
##        fileName = os.path.splitext(files)[0] # gets filename
##        outFile = fileName + ".jpg"
### Following line produces error
##        inFile.save(outFile)
## 
##    return()
##
##
##
##def eps2jpg2():
##    for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
##        f, e = os.path.splitext(infile)
##        outfile = f + ".jpg"
##        if infile != outfile:
##            try:
##                Image.open(infile).save(outfile)
##            except IOError:
##                print("cannot convert", infile)

frames = [50,98,141,178,208,228,239]
filenames = ["frame1","frame2","frame3","frame4","frame5","frame6","frame7"]

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(150):
        randomRed = random.randint(1,254)
        randomGreen = random.randint(1,254)
        randomBlue = random.randint(1,254)

        randomLength = random.randint(0,frames[i])
        randomTurn = random.randint(-95,95)

        pencolor(randomRed,randomGreen,randomBlue)
        forward(randomLength)
        right(randomTurn)
        goto(0,0)

    saveImage(filenames[i])

#simplified conversion code
    inFile = Image.open(filenames[i]+".eps")
    outFile = filenames[i] + ".jpg"
#following line produces the error: no such file or directory 'gs'
    inFile.save(outFile)

    clear()

write("done - close turtle window now")

done()
```

The error message which is generated by the first function and by the simplified conversion code is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sharland/Dropbox/computing_department/Languages and Systems/python/python_scripts/vine_animations/starburst_pulse.py", line 61, in <module>
    inFile.save(outFile,"JPEG")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1631, in save
    self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 361, in load
    self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp, scale)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 130, in Ghostscript
    gs = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 848, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1441, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gs` it is attempting to find is the [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) utility which it's calling as a subprocess. Install that and make sure that the `gs` command is on your PATH afterward. Since you're on OS X, if you use Homebrew, `ghostscript` is available through that.

Comment: Have tried installing ghostscript but it says it is only compatible with python 2.  Will try again and this time add `gs` command to PATH

Comment: added gs to path through adding `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/gs:$PATH"` to `.bash_profile` and `echo $PATH` is showing gs but I am still getting the same error as before.

Comment: That's not how PATH works. http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html If you install ghostscript through Homebrew or similar, it should already be in an appropriate place. It sounds like you might have tried to install a Python package named that?

Comment: looks like a went down the wrong path so to speak ... :-)

Comment: Yes I think I did install a python package named that.  I installed ghostscript through brew and it shows up in `brew list` but still hitting the error above.  Will try and uninstall python package and reinstall through homebrew.

Comment: Can you run `gs` from the command line? From the same place where you would be running your python script?

Comment: I can run `gs` from the command line from the same location I am running the python script

Comment: Moral of the story - don't run script through IDLE but through the terminal instead - many thanks for your time